# Pointer is being being masked when calling a C function from Fortran

Tags: c, cuda, fortran

## TL;DR

When I pass an array from Fortran to C, the array's address is incorrect in C. I've checked this by printing the address of the array in Fortran before the `CALL`, then stepping into the C function and printing the address of the argument.

- The Fortran pointer: `0x9acd44c0`
- The C pointer: `0xffffffff9acd44c0`

The upper dword of the C pointer has been set to `0xffffffff`. I'm trying to understand why this is happening, and only happening on the HPC cluster and not on a development machine.

### Context

I'm using a rather large scientific program written in Fortran/C++/CUDA. On some particular machine, I get a segfault when calling a C function from Fortran. I've found that a pointer is being passed to the C function with some bytes set incorrectly.

### Code Snippets

Every Fortran file in the program includes a common header file which sets up some options and declares the common blocks.

```
IMPLICIT REAL*8  (A-H,O-Z)
COMMON/NBODY/  X(3,NMAX), BODY(NMAX)
COMMON/GPU/    GPUPHI(NMAX)
```

The Fortran call site looks like this:

```
CALL GPUPOT(NN,BODY(IFIRST),X(1,IFIRST),GPUPHI)
```

And the C function, which is compiled by `nvcc`, is declared like so:

```
extern "C" void gpupot_(int *n,
                       double m[],
                       double x[][3],
                       double pot[]);
```

### GDB Output

I found from debugging that the value of the pointer to `pot` is incorrect; so any attempt to access that array will segfault.

When I ran the program with gdb, I put a break point just before the call to `gpupot` and printed the value of the `GPUPHI` variable:

```
(gdb) p &GPUPHI   
$1 = (PTR TO -> ( real(kind=8) (1050000))) 0x9acd44c0 <gpu_>
```

I then let the debugger step into the `gpupot_` C function, and inspected the value of the `pot` argument:

```
(gdb) p pot
$2 = (double *) 0xffffffff9acd44c0
```

All of the other arguments have the correct pointer values.

### Compiler options

The compiler options that are set for `gfortran` are:

```
 -fPIC -O3 -ffast-math -Wall -fopenmp -mcmodel=medium -march=native -mavx -m64
```

And `nvcc` is using the following:

```
-ccbin=g++ -Xptxas -v -ftz=true -lineinfo -D_FORCE_INLINES \
-gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
-gencode arch=compute_35,code=compute_35 -Xcompiler \
"-O3 -fPIC -Wall -fopenmp -std=c++11 -fPIE -m64 -mavx \
-march=native" -std=c++14 -lineinfo
```

For debugging, the `-O3` is replaced with `-g -O0 -fcheck=all -fstack-protector -fno-omit-frame-pointer`, but the behaviour (crash) remains the same.

Comment: You may have to turn off optimization (and add `-g`) to be sure that you're inspecting the correct value of `pot` when you step into `gnupot_`. Otherwise, it looks like you're getting [unwanted] sign extension of `GPUPHI` when it is passed to `gnupot_` You could print the addresses (in fortran) just before the call. And, have `gnupot_` do `printf` on them using `%p`. What about the other pointer values--do they have the same problem or is it just the one that is [seems to be] in GPU memory? At a guess, `-mcmodel=medium` might be an issue because it's in fortran but not C

Comment: What does the program symbol map say (e.g. output of `readelf -s`)? With `-mcmodel=medium`, most small symbols are linked below 2GB, but larger ones are linked above 2GB (which means the sign bit is set).

Comment: @CraigEstey I've updated the question to show my debugging options. The other pointer values are fine; just `pot` is bad. It's not actually in GPU memory, it's a plain fortran array.

Comment: @CraigEstey What should I be grepping for in `readelf`?

Comment: Do (e.g.) `readelf -s ./myexec | less`. In the `.symtab` section, look at the address for `GPUPHI` [and the others that you pass]. Does `GPUPHI` have a radically different address? I think you should be consistent with `-mcmodel`. Can you build without it? Does that help? Can you read x86 asm? If so, you could disassemble the _call_ in the fortran routine to be sure that it's not generating an instruction that sign extends. Does the fortran code _know_ it's calling a C/C++ routine (e.g. does fortran have the equiv of "extern C" for func declaration)?

Comment: OK, adding `-mcmodel=medium` to the `nvcc -Xcompiler` option seems to have fixed it up. I guess this inconsistency affected the call.

Comment: Glad you fixed it. Here's a good reference that may help further: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.4/gfortran.pdf Section 7.1 is about interoperability and 7.1.4 is about subroutine calling declarations/conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is prefaced by my top comments [and yours].

It looks like you're getting an [unwanted] sign extension of the address.

`gfortran` is being built with `-mcmodel=medium` but C does not.

With that option, larger symbols/arrays will be linked above 2GB [which has the sign bit set]

So, add the option to both or leave it off both to fix the problem.